# How can gave a View as default value in a View Function in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have this down function which I want the content carry a default value, I want this function get to work:

```
func viewFunction<Content: View>(content: Content = { Text("Hello!") }) -> some View {

    return content

}
```

I know that I can split the function for this reason, but I want to have the function which carries the default value for content, also I do not want to have 2 functions.

**my Goal**: I want be able use my function in form of: `viewFunction()`

---

**Update:**

> Swift doesn't have defaults for generic placeholders.

Comment: what are you trying to do, passing default value to generic function? why would you do that?

Comment: to having default value for content in inferring mode of function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most possible way is having 2 function's. Like down codes:

**PS: We cannot have the function which carries the default value for a generic type.**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {

        viewFunction(content: Text("Hello, world!"))
        
        viewFunction()
    }
}


func viewFunction<Content: View>(content: Content) -> some View {

    return content

}

func viewFunction() -> some View {

    return Text("Hello, world!")

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply with:

```swift
func viewFunction<Content: View>(content: () -> Content = { Text("hello") as! Content }) -> some View {
  return content()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer with `as!`-casting because it will preserve documentation without code generation.

But the general solution is to overload, because Swift doesn't have defaults for generic placeholders.

Note: this question is not SwiftUI-specific.

```swift
func viewFunction<Content: View>(content: Content) -> some View { content }

func viewFunction() -> some View {
  viewFunction(content: Text("Hello!"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AnyView` and return `EmptyView`. Example:

```
let shortcut: TabShortcut

var body: some View {
    guard let url = URL(string: shortcut.link) else {
        return AnyView(EmptyView())
    }

    let link = Link(destination: url) {
        Text("\(shortcut.title)")
    }

    return AnyView(link)
}
```

Comment: The goal is given default value to a generic type not solving an example.